# how to stop validate method to be fired from second time in struts

Tags: java

i have been facing a lot of problems doing these.For the first time validation is executed fine.now for the second time i need to call a specific function of a class that is an action class,but it in second time its again calling the validate method and throws this action:

```
com.LogingEx.validate(LogingEx.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:200)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
```